# Amazon S3 Copy between two buckets with different Authentication

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have two buckets, each with a Private ACL.

I have an authenticated link to the source:

```
String source = "https://bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/key?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=...&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=...Signature=..."
```

and have been trying to use the Java SDK `CopyObjectRequest` to copy it into another bucket using:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
  .standard()
  .withCredentials(provider)

AmazonS3URI sourceURI = new AmazonS3URI(URI(source))
CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(sourceURI.getBucket, sourceURI.getKey, destinationBucket, destinationKey);
s3Client.copyObject(request);
```

However I get `AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied` because My AWS credentials I've set the SDK up with do not have access to the source file.

Is there a way I can provide an authenticated source URL instead of just the `bucket` and `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported.  The PUT+Copy service API, which is used by `s3Client.copyObject()`, uses an internal S3 mechanism to copy of the object, and the source object is passed as `/bucket/key` -- not as a full URL. There is no API functionality that can be used for fetching from a URL, S3 or otherwise.

With PUT+Copy, the user making the request to S3...

> must have READ access to the source object and WRITE access to the destination bucket
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

The only alternative is download followed by upload.

Doing this from EC2... or a Lambda function running in the source region would be the most cost-effective, but if the object is larger than the Lambda temp space, you'll have to write hooks and handlers to read from the stream and juggle the chunks into a multipart upload... not impossible, but requires some mental gyrations in order to understand what you're actually trying to persuade your code to do.